# GNU ddrescue to copy directories or folders from hard disk

Tags: debian, data-recovery, external-hdd, ddrescue

Debian 9 (Stretch) laptop, and attached external hard disk in enclosure.
How to use GNU ddrescue to copy folders or files from failed hard disk? (not the whole disk image). For example, `/home` directory.

Comment: You can't do that. The tool is for rescuing disk images without regard to the data they contain

Comment: [Using `ddrescue` to recover a broken drive. Can I check the progress before the run is complete?](https://superuser.com/q/1090620/432690)

Answer (score 1):

That isn't for what the GNU `ddrescue` program is designed.

You can, however, make a copy of a specific partition, from which you want to copy the data, rescue the partition, and then mount it and copy the data from inside it to wherever you wish, I do that all the time, except I'm always copying the whole disks, which is only a small hassle when mounting it afterward.

Good luck.

Comment: I can't copy a full disk image since I have no dedicated media storage or separate PC for storing disk copies 500gb.

Comment: @triwo Then you cannot use GNU `ddrescue`. Simple as that.

Comment: what command to copy folders that contain corrupted data?

Comment: @triwo The only way I know of is just the mentioned `ddrescue` and then copy actual data from the created image. Sorry, I never have tried another approach. Maybe there is, but I somehow doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

Corrupted files and folders can be rescued up to a point by using [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and its companion [PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec), available for all the major Linux distros,
and included in freely downloadable rescue systems like
[the Ultimate Boot CD (UBCD)](https://www.ultimatebootcd.com/index.html) or [SystemRescue](https://www.system-rescue.org).

Comment: testdisk mainly recover partitions, photorec recover files on a partition. As I can remember, you can't choose a single folder.